# why node.js backend can't set cookie to frontend react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cookies

i have trouble when i try to send a cookie from node to react for login auth, when i test with insomnia it works with no problem.

this is the result test from insomnia there's a cookie in connection
[image: Insomnia]

this my devtools from chrome, as you guys can see there's nothing in here
[image: DevTools]

```
// custom config CORS
const configCors = {
    origin : 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials : true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}

// the cookie i want to set
res.cookie("refresh", refresh, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // in milliseconds
        })
```

Why cookies don't exist in devtools react.js, but only exist in insomnia when I test it

for information :
**Frontend React.js**,
**Backend Node.js**

Comment: can you attach screenshot of network request shown in network tab of chrome devtools ?.

Comment: @bogdanoff sure...[https://i.ibb.co/TBv7Crp/insomnia.jpg](from my console) and this is from my network [https://i.ibb.co/kQYX417/network.jpg](network)

Comment: The host is `localhost:5000` in the first picture - why would you expect the cookie be set for `localhost:3000`???? your fetch (on the CLIENT) would need to `include` `credentials` if you want to accept cookies in a request to `localhost:5000`

Comment: sorry, not `fetch` ... your "axios request" would need to include credentials, however that's done in axios

Comment: @JaromandaX you mean `withCredentials: true,`, of course i put it but some strange happen is the cookies after i login to dashboard and check the cookie with `document.cookie` nothing in here, i wonder why?

Comment: @Xander `httpOnly` cookies can't be accessed using javascript (`document.cookie` wont show it).

Comment: @Xander on insomnia I can see `/dashboard` is responding with data but in chrome dev tools its showing `404 ( not found)` for same endpoint. Can you investigate it ?